# How to run goimports on all folders except Godeps and .git?

Tags: go

How can I run `goimports` on all folders expect Godeps and .git from a Makefile?

Answer (score 10):

Use `find` to list all your `go` files and run a command `goimports -w` over it:

```
find . -name \*.go -not -path <FOLDER TO IGNORE> -not -path <ANOTHER FOLDER TO IGNORE> -exec goimports -w {} \;
```